# Automatic profile matching

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Developing a PHP/MySQL website where users can search for other users. We want to create an area where "automatic" profile matches can be shown. This means it compares the currently logged in user's profile to other users on the website and shows users who have marked the same options in their profile.

The site is built on WordPress so it uses a user_meta table to store all the data on a user.

Users

```
+----+-----------------+----------+
| id | user_login      | etc      |
+----+-----------------+----------+
|  1 | username1       | ...      |
|  2 | username2       | ...      |
|  3 | username3       | ...      |
+----+-----------------+----------+
```

User Meta

```
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| id | user_id     | meta_key    | meta_value  |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|  1 | 1           | zipcode     | 92027       |
|  2 | 1           | smoker      | Y           |
|  3 | 1           | something   | xyz         |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

I don't have any query started because conceptually I am still at a loss on how to approach this.

Results would ideally be sorted in order of most matches.

Answer (score 0):

CONCEPT only?

Might be an query extensive approach:

```
if (is_user_logged_in == TRUE) {
    1. Get all metas this profile have using GROUP query put them in an array( meta1 => 'element1', meta2 => 'element2')
    2. Foreach values in the array Run search SELECT * FROM wp_table WHERE meta1='element1
'   3. Count the results of 2, if greater than zero echo the other profiles
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So what I ended up doing:

Pull all the meta for currently logged in user. Then looped through all other users. For every other user I grabbed all their meta. I compared the meta values of the current user to each user individually. Each other user was given +1 if they had a meta value that matched. I made a new array with user IDs and how many matches they had. Sorted that array by the number of matches. I used WordPress' transient system to essentially cache that data for 24 hours so this process is not run over and over via pagination or the user coming and going from this one page. If the current user updates their profile, I also clear the transient as well.